# iBooks on Mavericks Beachballs Whenever Text Styling Occurs

Tags: crash, books, macos

Whenever I want to change text styling in iBooks the app becomes unresponsive. I kill it in the terminal (`killall iBooks`), and then the system reports that `CoreText.FontDownloadHelper` has crashed. My current theory is that if I'm to sort out `CoreText.FontDownloadHelper`, then the crash in iBooks won't occur any more. Am I right?

Here's the crash report, with the UUID removed.

```
Process:         CoreText.FontDownloadHelper [2865]
Path:            /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/CoreText.FontDownloadHelper.xpc/Contents/MacOS/CoreText.FontDownloadHelper
Identifier:      CoreText.FontDownloadHelper
Version:         1.1 (1)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [398]
Responsible:     CoreText.FontDownloadHelper [2865]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2013-10-22 20:17:31.634 -0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9 (13A603)
Report Version:  11


Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
Configuration error: Could not create listener. xpc_main() was probably called from a process that is not an XPC service bundle.

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libxpc.dylib                    0x00007fff8d637b06 xpc_main + 359
1   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8913d12b -[NSXPCListener resume] + 108
2   com.apple.CoreText.FontDownloadHelper 0x000000010a430f7b main + 106
3   libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff91b045fd start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87c4de6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87688f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8768bfb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87c4e662 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff864e043d _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 239
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff864e0152 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87c4de6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87688f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8768bfb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x00007fff8d642684  rbx: 0x00007f819950d620  rcx: 0x00000000000000ac  rdx: 0x0000000000000003
  rdi: 0x000000000000040b  rsi: 0x0000000010000003  rbp: 0x00007fff557d0bc0  rsp: 0x00007fff557d0b10
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x00000000000000ac  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x000000010a468010  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x00007fff8913d12b  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: 0x00007fff8d637b06  rfl: 0x0000000000010206  cr2: 0x00007f8199402000

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000000
Trap Number:     6
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Some people have been able to solve it by [activating disabled fonts](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23496158#23496158), but that doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get rid of this problem by doing this:

1. open Font Book
2. run `File > Restore Standard Fonts…`

That basically moves all user-installed fonts to `~/Library/Fonts (Removed)`. So I suppose the problem is caused by one (or more) of the manually installed fonts.